# how to solve derivative of a function including two absolute functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima, absolute-value

So I don't understand how to solve the derivative of a function with two absolute functions.

$$f(x) = |x - 1| + |x^2 - 2x|.$$

Here is the function. I need to solve the maximum and minimum values in the domain $[0,2]$ but can't figure out the derivative.

Comment: Note that the absolution is not differentiable at a point. So finding the max/min by setting the derivative to be zero might not work.

Comment: Have you tried making a sketch of the function? There are at most four functions you need to consider ($±|x - 1| ± |x^2 - 2x|$), but not all of them apply to the domain.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to solve by derivative, one way is to break it into smaller domains where signs remain the same.

For $0 \le x \le 1$, $f(x) =  -(x-1) - (x^2-2x) = 1+x-x^2$

For $1 \le x \le 2$, $f(x) =  (x-1) - (x^2-2x) = 3x-x^2-1$

Now when you differentiate, you get max of $f(x) = \frac{5}{4}$, at $x = \frac{1}{2}$ and $x = \frac{3}{2}$.